# How to prevent vim process substitution (ie. git ls echoing versus redirected to vim)

Tags: bash, git, shell, terminal

`git branch` drops the output to, seemingly, vim rather than just dumping the branch list straight to the terminal.

I know I could do something like `git config alias.ls '!git branch | cat'` but that doesn't play well with arguments.

Is there a way to simply disable git from redirecting to vim?

Fwiw, I'm using Oh My ZSH / ZSH; however, I tried similar commands in vanilla bash in both iTerm2 and Terminal with the same results.

Comment: What is `git ls` in the first place?

Comment: Ah, sorry, meant `git branch`

Comment: If output is redirected to _anything_, it's going to be your pager. If vim is acting as your pager, it'll be either something in your git config or your environment variables setting that up.

Comment: ...so `git --no-pager branch` f/e will have the same effect without the `| cat`

Comment: ...so, as a starting point: What does `declare -p PAGER` emit? If it says there's no such variable, I might jump to `git config -l | grep pager` (for want of patience to look up precise usage to query only what we care about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the pager you're using is `less`, unless otherwise specified.  However, regardless of the pager you're using, you can turn it off.

If you want the pager off for one command, do `git --no-pager branch` (for example), but note that the `--no-pager` goes before the command.  This is great for aliases.  If you want the pager off for all commands, set `core.pager` to `cat`, and Git will not invoke the pager.  There is not a way to disable it just for one command and not others.

Note that the pager is not invoked by default for commands where the output is not a TTY, so if you're scripting, it's automatically disabled.

Comment: Thanks! Bless your speedy answer :)